# How to bypass Salesforce MFA using trusted IP address?

Tags: loginflow, ip, mfa

[MFA will be required in Feb 2022](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352937&type=1&mode=1).

Looking to make it easier on the users, and bypass it for trusted/whitelisted **IP addresses**.

I know about the **Trusted Locations** automation in the Authenticator app, but that's not good enough - it requires GPS, which most people usually have turned off.  Users would have to get the phone and turn on GPS just to log in to Salesforce.  That's not much different than clicking the "Authorize" button in the app.

Additionally, the app frequently does not recognize the location even with GPS enabled.

I have seen a solution of using **Login Flows**, but that does not apply here, because that solution uses a custom MFA, not a Salesforce-native soon-to-be-required MFA.

Comment: Is _custom MFA_ something implemented outside of Salesforce? Please edit your question and provide more detail. do not reply in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I have just had a discussion with a Salesforce Support Agent about this topic today. Unfortunately, there is no options to bypass it at the moment.

They confirmed it.

The trusted ip ranges can be used to bypass primary methods like Email, SMS. MFA is the second method.

I created an idea here: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lgRZQAY

Let's vote for it

Comment: voted!  hopefully more people will start looking for this and voting as the deadline approaches

Answer (score 0):

With Salesforce Authenticator, if you turn on location services in the app, you can mark a "Trusted Location" and it won't ask you for a code.  Microsoft doesn't have that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to log in with a **combination** of:

- Trusted Device (ask your IT support and/or Salesforce what is it)
- Trusted Network